# JS files not loading on all pages in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I'm currently working on a project where I used an app that has been already built. I'm actually just upgrading that one. Now, the app has a lot of javascript files. Most of them are located in vendor/assets/javascripts and some in app/assets/javascripts. For the app, that works fine. For the pages I make, it just doesn't work! I.e. I created a new model where I have the date as a field. Now I wanted to use the datepicker which is located in vendor/assets/javascripts. It loads on the other page, but on my projects/new jquery is missing, datapicker is missing... It doesn't recognize the funcions.

application.js looks like this

```
//= require jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js
//= require pace/pace.min.js
//= require peity/jquery.peity.min.js
//= require slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js
//= require inspinia.js
```

On the pages where the js work, they work flawlessly and they are not added on those specific pages. They are included somehow through the app.

application.html.erb

```
<!-- Include style per-controller - vendor plugins -->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] if ::Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.css") %>

    <!-- Main css styles -->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

    <!-- Main javascript files -->
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you identify which ones are loading and which aren't?

Comment: I think yes. On the projects/new page that I created after, the files from vendor/assets/javascripts are not loading. I have some js code on the page so I could have the datepicker for the field. The console says ".datepicker is not a function" and the datepicked js files are in vendor so I supose that part is not being loaded here. But I'm frustrated because of the fact that it's being loaded on one part of the app.